# How to prevent SBT from resolving the same dependencies for different projects

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a .sbt file with 4 projects. They all share many dependencies. When I `Refresh SBT` in Idea, it seems to resolve all dependencies over and over again, even if they have been previously resolved in other projects.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [cached resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html#Cached+resolution):

> The intended performance improvement is that the second and third subprojects can take advantage of the resolved minigraphs from the first one and avoid duplicated work.

Try it with setting:

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```